# Do creatures with fractional HD have all the other benefits of full HD creatures?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Some small animals, e.g. rats, have fractional HD, which means that they have less hit points than animals with the same constitution and full HD have.

Suppose you have (for example) an outsider with 1/2 HD. Does it have +1 BAB and 8+int mod skill points, or 0 BAB, or less skill points?

Comment: I believe the text says somewhere whether this is rounded up or down and how to treat <1HD creatures.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All creatures that have less than one HD are considered to have one.

Normally the *Monster Manual* (or *Dungeon Master's Guide*) provides such information, but I am not sure which one... Creatures get good or bad scores according to their types...

[This document](http://www.d20resources.com/modern.d20.srd/creature.types/) provides what you need, also it states HD categories as 1 *or less*, 2, 3 etc...